# Excel - matching multiple strings of two columns and turn true shared strings in third column

Tags: excel, excel-formula, excel-2010

Example:

```
      A1          B1
1   white dog   black dog       
2   big tall    tall building
3   wood        green wood
4   big house   green wood
5   long way    street
```

I want to turn C1 true if A1 has one string match or full string match of B1 else C1 turn false:

```
        A1             B1                  C1    

  1   white dog        black dog           true
  2   big tall         tall building       true
  3   wood             green wood          true 
  4   big house        green wood          false
  5   long way         street              false
```

Answer (score 1):

`=SUMPRODUCT(0+ISNUMBER(SEARCH(" "&TRIM(MID(SUBSTITUTE(A1," ",REPT(" ",LEN(A1))),LEN(A1)*(ROW(INDEX(A:A,1):INDEX(A:A,1+LEN(A1)-LEN(SUBSTITUTE(A1," ",""))))-1)+1,LEN(A1)))&" "," "&B1&" ")))>0`

Regards

Comment: This doesn`t find the match between two columns(on the cells level)

Comment: @DemGergo Not sure what you mean. It works for the data you provided. Perhaps give me an example where it doesn't work.

Comment: The first cell didn`t work(because somehow it didn`t recognise the first cell) but others works fine. So the code you provided is very good!